# java code line, class count, method count ... support plugin in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ
Do you have a plugin that allows you to view quantified numbers of files in the current project, such as code lines, class counts, and method counts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two candidate plugins:

- Statistics: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4509-statistic
- MetricsReloaded: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/93-metricsreloaded

These will both show you most of what you asked for including "numbers of files in the current project, such as code lines, class counts" but not including "method counts".

Both plugins are compatible with IntelliJ 2017.2 (at least). The Statistics plugin is more active, has more downloads and has been updated more recently (April 7, 2018).